# How to convert the mysql result to an array in php?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am trying to convert the result of mysql to an array.Following is my code. But it return `[]` this.

Anybody help me to solve this please...

**result.php**

```
$prep =$mysqli->prepare("select name,location from token where sen_uid=?");
$prep->bind_param("s",$id);
$prep->execute();
$result= $prep->get_result(); 
$rows= array();
while($r= $result->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
     $rows[] = $r;
}
$obj= json_encode($rows);
```

As I want the output of `json` to be an array

Answer (score 1):

I've edited my code like this.Now it is working.

**result.php**

```
$prep =$mysqli->prepare("select name,location from token where sen_uid=?");

$prep->bind_param("s",$id);
$prep->execute();
$result= $prep->get_result(); 
$payload= array();
while($r= $result->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    $payload[]=array('name' =>$r['name'],
                       'lc' =>$r['location'],

        );
}
$obj= json_encode($payload);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, let's talk about....
`while($r= $result->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC))`
What you are doing here is setting `$r` as an associative array, then setting that full array inside `$rows`; so if `$result`  did return anything, it would be multiplied inside `$rows`.
Maybe what you are after is something like this?

```
$prep =$mysqli->prepare("select name,location from token where sen_uid=?");     
//should the bind_param function be i instead of s? i means integer and s means string
//$prep->bind_param("i",$id);
$prep->bind_param("s",$id);
$prep->execute();
$result= $prep->get_result(); 
$rows= array();
//for an array like [0][0], [0][1] use
//$rows= $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
//for an arary like [0]['name'], [0]['location'] use:
$rows= $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$obj= json_encode($rows);
```

The execution of the query looks correct. I'd maybe add some error checking to ensure that prepare didn't fail. Have you tried running this query inside MySQL to see if you get results?

Edit; In fact, `while` is completely pointless in this as `$r` would only ever be set once. I think this issue sits mainly within a broken prepared query.

```
if($prep =$mysqli->prepare("select name,location from token where sen_uid=?")){     
    //should the bind_param function be i instead of s? i means integer and s means string
   //$prep->bind_param("i",$id);
    $prep->bind_param("s",$id);
    if(!$prep->execute()){
         print_r("Execute error: ".$mysqli->error);
    }
    $result= $prep->get_result(); 
    $rows= array();
    //for an array like [0][0], [0][1] use
    //$rows= $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
    //for an arary like [0]['name'], [0]['location'] use:
    $rows= $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $obj= json_encode($rows);
}else{
    print_r("Prepare error: ".$mysqli->error);    
}
```

For debugging purposes, add error checking like the above snippet

Comment: I've tried to write the output to a text file , this returns null.

Comment: @NeethuM Have you tried running the code with error checking? please also run the query you are trying to execute in phpmyadmin/mysql cli to see if you are getting a result

Comment: Yeah query is working perfectly , but `json_encode` return `null`

Comment: Do you have any errors in php? Do you have the `mysqlnd` driver installed as `get_result();` will throw out a php error if that's the case.

Comment: Sorry i've double checked my code , I can't find any error in my code.What would be the problem?

Comment: Please see this question as there is an error somewhere if you are 100% sure that query works. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any data related to your query in DB ?
if yes then try to change

this

$prep->bind_param("s",$id);

to

$prep->bind_param("i",$id);

Comment: It is working. I've given id as `varchar`.So i think instead of using `i` `s` is prefered ,right?

Comment: If you have issues, you can check the log of server

Answer (score -1):

you need to use array_push method to push the object(value) into an array.

```
$prep =$mysqli->prepare("select name,location from token where sen_uid=?");
$prep->bind_param("s",$id);
$prep->execute();
$result= $prep->get_result(); 
$rows= array();
while($r= $result->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
     array_push($rows,$r);
}
$obj= json_encode($rows);
```

Comment: This solves nothing. You've really not changed anything as `array_push` works in the same way as `$row[] = $var`

Comment: what you trying to say? the variable $rows now returns []?
Tell me the reason for the downvote.

Comment: I've already stated the reason for my downvote. `$row[]=$var` == `array_push($row,$var);`

Comment: First understand the question clear then downvote if it not satisfies.

Comment: Your answer DOES NOT satisfy the question tho. You do the exact same thing as the OP did